# Wi-Fi Atheros QCA8171 driver not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, atheros

I’ve just decided to move to Ubuntu 14.04 with my Toshiba L50-A-19M and a Wi-Fi board Atheros QCA8171, yet I can’t connect to my home wireless network. I've done exactly the steps mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/880960/atheros-qca8171-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04), yet when I type "make" I get:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/build M=/home/stefano/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic'
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/user/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u/.tmp_versions/compat.mod’: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [crmodverdir] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2**
```

Please, give me some hints to get the driver updated!

Comment: Post the results from `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` as I don't think the QCA8171 is a wifi device

Comment: @Jeremy31 Good one!  ;-)

Comment: 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0612]
 Kernel driver in use: ath9k
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:10a1] (rev 10)
 Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:fa40]
 Kernel driver in use: alx

Answer (score 0):

So usually when there's a **Permission denied** error, it is because your account doesn't have access to that directory. In this case, that's kind of weird since it looks like you're in your own home directory, but in either case, try running `sudo make` instead of just `make` and it should fix your problem.

Comment: unfortunately this is the output:                                ...
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/stefano/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2

Comment: What is the actual error? That's just the log saying an error occurred. (I think)

Comment: Is this the correct answer?

Comment: it was a make-related problem: reinstalled and fixed